# Find the word in the line, the beginning of a specific letter and the word, the end of the same letter

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net

Given a string with words,separated by problems, I need to find which word occurs before: which begins with the letter "k" or ends with "k"

I tried make this with Mid and Len operators, but now i need this with Substring and Length

```
Sub uncorrect(ByVal s As String, ByRef res As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim t, w As String
    s = s + " "
    w = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        t = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If t = " " Then
            If (Mid(w, 1, 1) = "k") Then
                res = "Word, begin with k"
                Exit Sub
            Else
                If (Mid(w, Len(w), 1) = "l") Then
                    res = "Word, end with k"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
            w = ""
        Else
            w = w + t
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub trying(ByVal s As String, ByRef res As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim mass = s.Split(" ")
    For i = 0 To mass.Length - 1
        If mass(i).Substring(1, 1) = "k" Then
            res = "Word, begin with k"
            Exit For
        Else
            If mass(i).Substring(mass(i).Length - 1, 1) = "k" Then
                res = "Word, end with k"
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Actual output very unstable: or empty result textbox, or error

Comment: Thank all of you
But I found a mistake
`mass(i).Substring(1, 1) = "k"` => `mass(i).Substring(0, 1) = "k"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use substring if you just want one character. You can get a character just by specifying the index with the default property.

```
Sub trying(ByVal s As String, ByRef res As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim mass = s.Split(" "c)
    For i = 0 To mass.Length - 1
        If mass(i)(0) = "k"c Then
            res = "Word, begin with k"
            Exit For
        Else
            If mass(i)(mass(i).Length - 1) = "k"c Then
                res = "Word, end with k"
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a function using Linq which returns a List(Of String) with the words meeting the criteria. I trimmed the words of any punctuation and the tested with String.StartsWith and String.EndsWith. For testing purposes I printed the result to the Immediate window.

```
Private Function GetWords(input As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim words = input.Split(" "c)
    Dim Kwords = (From S In words
                  Let TrimmedS = S.Trim(New Char() {","c, "."c}) 'and whatever other puncuation you need to trim
                  Where TrimmedS.StartsWith("K", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse TrimmedS.EndsWith("K", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                  Select TrimmedS).ToList
    Return Kwords
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim KWords = GetWords("The quick fox")
    Debug.Print("The quick fox")
    For Each w In KWords
        Debug.Print(w)
    Next
    Dim KWords1 = GetWords("Kick, scream, and knock out.")
    Debug.Print("Kick, scream, and knock out.")
    For Each w In KWords1
        Debug.Print(w)
    Next
End Sub
```

Result:

```
The quick fox  
quick  
Kick, scream, and knock out. 
Kick 
knock
```

Comment: This is probably the most modern solution, but the teacher will not accept with the reason "Linq not explained in lectures"

Comment: @Lophi That is a shame. A student who has the initiative to move beyond the lectures should be rewarded.